# Variance in function types (Scala)

Tags: scala, function, types, variance

So I'm trying to understand variance in Scala. I know that if A1 >: A2 and B1 <: B2, then (A1 => B1) <: (A2 => B2), in other words functions are contravariant in the domain and covariant in the domain.
In this example, the first two cases respects this rule but I don't understand why CASE3 is correct, because the two functions are covariant in the domain (Cat <: Animal) so it should not be allowed.  Moreover, inside the function fun2 I pass an object of type Dog as input to b, which shouldn't be accepted because the function I'm passing should only get Cat as input.
Please help me understand this topic better.

```
class Animal{}

class Cat extends Animal{}
class Persian extends Cat{}
class Dog extends Animal{}

def fun(a:Cat => Animal): Unit = {
  a(new Persian)
}
def fun2(b: Animal => Cat): Unit = {
  b(new Dog)
}

fun(Animal => new Cat) //CASE1: OK: contrarvariant in domain, covariant in codomain
fun2(Cat => new Animal) //CASE2: NO: covariant in domain, contravariant in codomain
fun2(Cat => new Cat) //CASE3: OK but I don't know why it works because it's covariant in the domain
```

Comment: If you use propper syntax then the compiler fails as expected: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/hKJl26QeSvW9A216dmzkBw/4

Comment: tl;dr: In `Cat => new Cat` the first `Cat` is a variable called `Cat` inferred to be of type `Animal`.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why CASE3 is correct.

It's not. And it won't work when you will try to pass an *object* of type `Cat => Cat`. Right now I'm not sure what are you passing, but your syntax is not the correct one to achieve your intention. For example, either use eta-expansion, or try to pass a function:

```
  def myMethod(x: Cat): Cat = new Cat
  fun2(myMethod) // type mismatch; found: Cat => Cat; required: Animal => Cat
  
  val f: Cat => Cat = x => x // the identity function
  fun2(f) // type mismatch; found: Cat => Cat; required: Animal => Cat
```

This also answers your other question.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify exactly what's happening here. Alin's answer is correct, I just want to emphasize what your current code is doing. Our two functions look like this.

```
def fun(a: Cat => Animal): Unit
def fun2(b: Animal => Cat): Unit
```

Now your first call

```
fun(Animal => new Cat)
```

`Animal` is *not* the name of the type, it's the name of a local variable. So the function is one that takes a single argument (called `Animal`), ignores it, and returns a `Cat`. `fun` expects a `Cat => Animal`, so the inferred type of `Animal` will, incidentally, be `Cat`. What you probably meant to write was

```
fun((_: Animal) => new Cat)
```

Now the second one.

```
fun2(Cat => new Animal)
```

Same problem. `Cat` is a local variable whose *name* happens to be `Cat`. Since `fun2` wants an `Animal => Cat`, the inferred type of `Cat` is `Animal` (which is fine; since we never used the variable, the compiler is free to infer whatever type is pleases). However, the return type *must* be `Animal`, which fails because, as you've correctly pointed out, functions are covariant in the result type. Again, to get the argument behavior you wanted, you probably meant

```
fun2((_: Cat) => new Animal)
```

Finally, the third example.

```
fun2(Cat => new Cat)
```

This one tripped me up for a minute, but it's the same principle. `Cat` is a function argument that's unused. It might *look* like it's used on the right-hand side, but it's not. The word after `new` *must* be a type name, not a local variable, so the left-hand-side `Cat` and the right-hand-side `Cat` have *no relation* to each other. Since `fun2` expects an `Animal => Cat`, the inferred type of `Cat` (the variable on the left) is `Animal`, and the function returns a `Cat` as expected. If you write the function to take an explicit argument of type `Cat`, it will fail as you would expect.

```
fun2((_: Cat) => new Cat)
```

Comment: Good observation! I tripped for a minute too and was wondering why it's code compiled in the first place.